# Is it possible to make the font size static for the Google Ad sence in all the pages?

Tags: adsense

Is it possible to make the font size static for the Google Ad sence in all the pages?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to configure that in the Google Adsense Ad Setup page, as it is the only way you can configure a Google Adsense Ad without breaking the terms of service.

In short, you just need to create a palette and use it on all ads you create.